# Is it possible to access each pixel value using ImageJ

Tags: java, imagej

I'm starting a project for college that uses ImageJ and Micro Manager. I want to be able to access each pixel of the image taken from a snapshot of the camera feed. My goal is to be able to apply a custom built function to each pixel on the snapshot of the image. Is it possible to do this using ImageJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, but at which level do you want to work: ImageJ macros or dive into the java code?

If you stay at the macros level, I don't think that you can access the pixel values.

However, if you want to do a little bit of programming, ImageJ uses the ImageProcessor class, which is extended according to the encoding type: ByteProcessor, ShortProcessor, BinaryProcessor, ColorProcessor. Then, you can access the pixel values using the methods getPixels(), getPixel(x,y), getPixelValue(x,y). But be careful to the encoding type, these methods are encoding specific.

Comment: Yes I will need to do some java programming for it, the macros don't seem capable of doing what I want, I have to build a GUI as well which would be simpler to use with on screen buttons. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: ImageJ offers a way to build a GUI, but I don't find it easy to use. Some IDE offer easier way to build a GUI.

Comment: If you want to do some programing, then you will have to create a class that implements PluginFilter.

Comment: You certainly can access individual pixels using an ImageJ macro; see [getPixel](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#getPixel) and [setPixel](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#setPixel). However, it is slower than Java code.

Comment: @FiReTiTi "ImageJ offers a way to build a GUI" -- Are you talking about GenericDialog? If so, check out the new [parameterized scripts](http://imagej.net/Script_parameters) feature of ImageJ2. Much nicer IMHO!